# C# Json deserialize - property as variable

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have problem. From json: https://api.csgofast.com/price/all I would like to get property name as variable. Can I do it with Newtonsoft Json library? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It was very hard reading the json, but one thing for sure - the keys in it are not valid `C#` property nor field names, so neither would work. Your only short is a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize this JSON into a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` like this:

```
var prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, decimal>>(json);
```